# How to add Sublime text to dash

Tags: unity-dash, sublime-text

I tried 2 types of links and it still I cant add it! I use the unregistered 64 version. [On Ubuntu forums](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73532/cant-add-sublime-text-to-the-gnome-shell-dock) and [external site](http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/)

Why is it not coming in the dash board. What is wrong? I even restarted the system to check if it came after the restart after the .desktop file. While the solution listed on the ubuntu forum asks to enter "main menu", there is no match in mine.

Comment: you are referring to dash, not launcher, right?

Comment: the left side icons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Open Terminal and write this command

   `sudo sublime /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop`

   This will create a file name sublime.desktop in the user/share/applications/ folder and open it for you.
2. Copy paste the following content in it and save the file

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Name=Sublime Text 2
   *#Only KDE 4 seems to use GenericName, so we reuse the KDE strings.*
   *#From Ubuntu's language-pack-kde-XX-base packages, version 9.04-20090413.*
   GenericName=Text Editor 
   Exec=sublime
   Terminal=false
   Icon=/usr/lib/Sublime Text 2/Icon/48x48/sublime_text.png
   Type=Application
   Categories=TextEditor;IDE;Development
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow
   [NewWindow Shortcut Group]
   Name=New Window
   Exec=sublime -n
   TargetEnvironment=Unity
   ```
3. You will see the Sublime-Text icon in the dash-board. right click the icon and click

   Lock in Launcher

Comment: This is exactly a copy-paste of the "external link" I have provided in the question! I have already said it doesnt work.

Comment: It worked for me.

Comment: This does not work for a portable archive downloaded from sublimetext.com, replaced "sublime" command with a full path to "sublime_text" executable, but it doesn't work. I have it in the dashboard, but clicking the icon does not run the editor. Not sure if this works at all. Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit.

Comment: UPDATE: it works but you need to rename the "Sublime Text 2" directory to "SublimeText2" so that it doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: I also had to remove those `*` characters before the comment lines.

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 13.04 and it still works!

Answer (score 8):

**STEP 1**

Download the tarfile that suits you best and extract it. Here’s the command to extract tar.bz2 files:

```
tar xf Sublime\ Text\ 2.0.1\ x64.tar.bz2
```

You’ll notice that I got the 64-bit version. The reason is that it’s lightning fast. So, go for that if you can!

**STEP 2**

You’ll get a “Sublime Text 2″ folder after extraction. This folder contains all the files that Sublime Text will need. So we have to move that folder somewhere more appropriate. Like the “/opt/” folder :

```
sudo mv Sublime\ Text\ 2 /opt/
```

**STEP 3**

At some point you’d want to be able to call Sublime Text from the Terminal by just typing “sublime”. To do that, we’ll just create a symbolic link in “/usr/bin” like thus:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime
```

**STEP 4**

Now that our files are at the right place, we need to create a launcher in Unity. To do this, we’re going to create a .desktop file in “/usr/share/applications”:

```
sudo sublime /usr/share/applications/sublime.desktop
```

And paste the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Sublime Text 2
# Only KDE 4 seems to use GenericName, so we reuse the KDE strings.
# From Ubuntu's language-pack-kde-XX-base packages, version 9.04-20090413.
GenericName=Text Editor

Exec=sublime
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/Sublime Text 2/Icon/48x48/sublime_text.png
Type=Application
Categories=TextEditor;IDE;Development
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow

[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=sublime -n
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

As you can see, these lines are quite straightforward. Go ahead and experiment a bit with them.

**STEP 5**

Now you would probably want to open all text files with Sublime Text 2. The easiest way to do that is to open up the file associations list:

```
sudo sublime /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

And replace all occurrences of gedit.desktop with sublime.desktop. Tada ! There you go. You now have Sublime Text 2 installed on Unity on Ubuntu 12.04, like a pro.

*Source: http://www.technoreply.com/how-to-install-sublime-text-2-on-ubuntu-12-04-unity/*

Comment: Your`e the best dude!!

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest way to add Sublime Text 2 to the Unity launcher. Open a terminal and type:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/.local/share/applications/ --create-new
```

Fill out the fields in the form and click OK. You can now find Sublime Text 2 in all the same locations as the other installed applications on your computer. When you launch Sublime Text 2, right click its icon and "Lock To Launcher".

---

*Note*: The application shortcut will only be visible for your current user. If this unacceptable, change `~/.local/share/applications/` to `/usr/share/applications/` and add `sudo` to the start of the command.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start by assuming your problem is that Sublime Text 2 does not appear when you search for it in the Dash.

After creating a launcher as specified in the second link you posted, search for the launcher using the Dash. You should then be able to pin the app to the launcher once it starts up.

You want to search for "sublime" not "main menu."  Not sure how GNOME Shell works, but there is no main menu in Unity.

In the event that Sublime does show up when searching, and your problem is just the pinning, you should be able to pin to the launcher by simply dragging the .desktop file you created to the launcher.

Answer (score 1):

```
php /usr/bin/sblm
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and Search for `/usr/bin sblm` and select. You can set it by going to `edit -> Settings` in FileZilla, and then go to Filetype Associations section and add the filetypes and the editor you want for them. `/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text` is an executable path of the sublime text editor.